# Solvability of the equations $x^n \equiv a \pmod p$ and $x^n \equiv a \pmod {p^e}$ where $p$ is an odd prime, $p \not \mid a$ and $p \not \mid n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I try to give a proof of the following proposition, but not quite sure if the proof is correct. Can anyone please help verify my proof? Thanks in advance!

> If $p$ is an odd prime, $p \not\mid a$, and $p \not\mid n$, then if $x^n \equiv a \pmod p$ is
> solvable, so is $x^n \equiv a \pmod {p^e}$ for all $e \geq 1$. All these congruences have the same
> number of solutions.

My proof: Let $d = (n,\phi(p)) = (n,p-1)$. There exists $g\in \mathbb{Z}$ which is simutaneously a primitive root $\mod p$ and a primitive root $\mod {p^e}$. The equation $x^n \equiv a \pmod p$ is solvable iff $a = g^b$ for some integer $b$ with $d \mid b$, and the number of inequivalent solutions is precisely $d$. Moreover, the equation $x^n \equiv a \pmod {p^e}$ is solvable iff $a = g^{b'}$ for some integer $b'$ with $d' = (n,\phi(p^e)) \mid b$, and the number of inequivalent solutions is $d'$. Straightforward calculations show that $d = d'$, which concludes the proof.

**edit:** Suppose $a=g^b$, $x=g^y$. Then the equation $x^n\equiv a\pmod p$ is equivalent to $g^{ny}\equiv g^{b}\pmod p$, which in turn is equivalent to $ny\equiv b\pmod {\phi(p)}$. The latter is solvable iff $(n,\phi(p))\mid b$. The proof is from Kenneth Ireland's number theory book.

Comment: Are you sure that "$x^n \equiv a$ is solvable iff $a = g^b, d\mid b$? In particular, since the RHS doesn't involve $n$ (and the LHS doesn't involve $b$), that claim seems dubious to me.  Maybe if you clarify the relationship between $b, n$, that claim might be true.

Comment: $d$ divided $b$ $\mod p-1$ and $d$ need not divide $b$ as integers. Further how did you conclude $b'$ divided $b$ ?

Comment: @CalvinLin I have edited to clarify the claim. $d = (n, \phi(p))$, as is claimed at the begining, so the RHS actually involve $n$.

Comment: @Balajisb I think since $d\mid p-1$, there is no essential difference between $d\mid (b\mod p-1)$ and $d\mid b$? Also, I think it is sufficient to show that $\{b: x^n\equiv g^b \pmod p$ is solvable$\} = \{b': x^n\equiv g^{b'} \pmod {p^e} $is solvable$\}$.

Comment: I see. Nice. I think your proof is fine though in your previous comment it should be $\{b: x^n=g^b \mod p\} =\{b' \mod p-1 : x^n = g^{b'} \mod p^{e}$.